# Magento 2 How to get quote in collect rates custom shipping

Tags: magento2, quote

I need to get a current quote from my custom shipping model:

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request){
  $quote = $this->getQuote(); // how????
}
```

how can I achieve this in checkout frontend and create an order in the backend?

Thanks.

Comment: What data do you need from the quote? The current answer will definitely create an infinite loop. Most data in the quote / what you need is available in the $request object. Please explain what it is you are trying to do with the quote at this point. By loading the quote it will call collect totals etc which in turn will call collectRates

Answer (score -1):

to get quote in CollectRates Method

```
    $items = $request->getAllItems();
    $firstItem = null;

    if ($items != null{
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $firstItem */
        $firstItem = reset($items);
    }
    
    if ($firstItem != null){
        $quote = $firstItem->getQuote();
        if ($quote instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote) {
            // found quote, code for quote
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want infinite loop because that's how you get infinite loop.
https://dev98.de/2018/07/23/how-a-wrong-carrier-implementation-causes-a-server-outage/